# Java, find duplicate and unique integers from two arrays

Tags: java, arrays

I am passing two integer arrays and trying to find duplicates and unique values.
But my output looks like this

```
[]
[18, 2, 5, 1, 7, 2]
```

What am I doing wrong?

```
import java.util.*;
//unique and duplicate of two arrays
class uniqueDup {
    public int dupUnique(int[] array1, int[] array2){
        ArrayList<Integer> unique = new ArrayList<>();    
        ArrayList<Integer> dup = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i=0; i<array1.length+1; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<array2.length+1; j++){
                if(array1[i] == array2[j]){
                    dup.add(array1[i]);
                } else {
                    unique.add(array1[i]);
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(dup);
        System.out.println(unique);
        return 0;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        uniqueDup test = new uniqueDup();
        int arraya[] = {18,2,5,1,7,2,4};
        int arrayb[] = {18,1,44,1,22,124,1,21};
        test.dupUnique(arraya,arrayb);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's definetly not the output that this program produces.

Comment: Your code (as posted) throws `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` exception since your code **wrongfully** presumes the existence of `array[array.length]` element.

Comment: this output is not **POSSIBLE** . where is the `Exception`.

Comment: apologies, I messed up. The result I was getting was from a earlier program with same class name.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public int dupUnique(int[] array1, int[] array2){
    ArrayList<Integer> unique = new ArrayList<>();    
    ArrayList<Integer> dup = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i=0; i<array1.length; i++){
        boolean duplicate = false;
        for(int j=0; j<array2.length; j++){
            if(array1[i] == array2[j]){
                dup.add(array1[i]);
                duplicate = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!duplicate) {
            unique.add(array1[i]);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(dup);
    System.out.println(unique);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you!. But it does not list unique elements properly.
I passed 2 arrays : 
 int arraya[] = {18,2,5,1,7,2,4};
 int arrayb[] = {18,1,44,1,22,124,1,21};
Output : [18, 1]
[2, 5, 7, 2, 4] ... it missed unique elements 44,22,etc

Answer (score 0):

Different approach: You can insert all values into a `HashMap` with the `Key` as the `Integer`  and the `Value` as the count. From the `Entry<Integer, Integer>` you can then identify not only the duplicates and the unique entries, but also the count:

```
public static Set<Entry<Integer, Integer>> findDup(int [] a, int [] b) {
    HashMap<Integer, Integer> entries = new HashMap<>();

    for (Integer i:a) 
        entries.put(i, entries.get(i) == null ? 1 : entries.get(i) + 1);

    for (Integer i:b) 
        entries.put(i, entries.get(i) == null ? 1 : entries.get(i) + 1);


    return entries.entrySet();
}
```

The `entries.put()` places each entry in the hash map, with the value of:

- 1 (item not contained in map yet)
- count + 1 (item already in map)

You can then find the duplicates and unique entries like so:

```
for (Entry<Integer, Integer> entry: findDup(a, b)) 
    if (entry.getValue() > 1) 
        System.out.println("duplicate: " + entry.getKey() + " (count = " + entry.getValue() + ")");
    else 
        System.out.println("unique: " + entry.getKey() );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class ArraysUniqueDupNumbersOrder {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int[] array1 = {18,2,5,1,7,2,4};
        int[] array2 = {18,1,44,1,22,124,1,21};
        ArrayList<Integer> unique = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Integer> dup = new ArrayList<>();

        // get the duplicate (common) numbers
        // get the unique numbers of array1 when compared to array2
        for(int i=0; i<array1.length; i++){
            boolean duplicate = false;
            for(int j=0; j<array2.length; j++){
                if(array1[i] == array2[j]){
                    dup.add(array1[i]);
                    duplicate = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!duplicate) {
                unique.add(array1[i]);
            }
        }

        // Add the unique numbers of array2 when compared to array1
        for(int j=0; j<array2.length; j++){
            boolean duplicate = false;
            for(int i=0; i<array1.length; i++){
                if(array1[i] == array2[j]){
                    duplicate = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!duplicate) {
                unique.add(array2[j]);
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Given two arrays: "+Arrays.toString(array1) + " and "+Arrays.toString(array2));
        System.out.println("Duplicates are: "+dup);
        System.out.println("Unique elements in the order from 2 arrays: "+unique);
    }

}
```

---

Output:-
Given two arrays: [18, 2, 5, 1, 7, 2, 4] and [18, 1, 44, 1, 22, 124, 1, 21]

Duplicates are: [18, 1]

Unique elements in the order from 2 arrays: [2, 5, 7, 2, 4, 44, 22, 124, 21]

More details of this code is available in [github](https://github.com/raghu-icecraft/java-practice/blob/master/arrays/src/ArraysUniqueDupNumbersOrder.java)